# When an optimization algorithm uses another method as the initial parameters

Tags: optimization, numerical-optimization, initial-value-problems

I have an optimization algorithm which is somehow similar to Bi-level optimization problem. Let's assume there is an algorithm (Alg1) form the literature as the state of the art for the problem.

I designed my own algorithm to solve the problem, but it doesn't provide a solution superior to Alg1, however if i use the Alg1's early solution (its first iteration) as the initial point of my algorithm, then it would converge to a better optimal point.

So how should i consider this regarding the novelty and how to represent my algorithm in general?

Comment: Just try and be clear in the paper in how you use it. a.k.a. as some kind of a "post-processing" of the solution of the other algorithm. Then you can say with a good conscience that you find a better solution. It could be that the first algorithm stops searching after some time $t$ that has been chosen to make it appear reasonably quick and practically useful but would find better solutions if allowed to search longer.

Comment: I also noticed i can use the result of Alg1 after a few iterations to put my algorithm in the right path. So i do not need to wait till first algorithm converges, and it makes the whole package faster than Alg1.

Comment: Ok just try and describe as detailed as you can in the paper what you do and why. Sometimes *best performance* is not the most important, but price of required materials, speed, implementability, usability in practical contexts, ability to combine with other algorithms, to use less electricity so that battery lasts longer or many other factors.